# Google Analytics & Facebook Connect referral

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-analytics

I'm currently working for a company which uses a lot of Facebook Connect. On their website, that's their main Call to Action.

I can see plenty of visitors coming from Facebook as a referrer and it looks like these people are actually only connecting to the Facebook connect.

I decided to add the domain "s-static.ak.facebook.com" (the one giving all those referrals) to the Referral Exclusion List. However, I'm still getting as much referrals as before.

Do you have any idea what I could do?

Note: I don't want to exclude that traffic, I just want GA to avoid counting this domain as a referral. It's like 40% of the traffic, so it's clearly weird.

Comment: Sorry Pierre is my question comes across as vague, English's my second language:

People go onto your login page and click the Facebook login button or however you phrased it. Then they are taken to Facebook and then back to your site? Is that the flow?

Answer (score 2):

Adding Facebook (s-static.ak.facebook.com) to the referral exclusion list actually worked. I was still seing plenty of users coming from this source because old users where still attributed to this "old" source.

If I segment users by New vs Returning, I can now see that users are coming from various sources and not only from Facebook.

Here is what I'd recommend:

1. Add Facebook to the referral exclusion list (s-static.ak.facebook.com)
2. Create a new profile to avoid getting old data

Comment: Hey Pierre! Thanks for the answer! Quick question, does your solution support the problem of Facebook Connect? My problem is that people are landing on the website.. clicking on fb connect, taken to fb and then come back once they accept.. and google is seeing that as the user came initially from Facebook. I just want to make sure that if I add that to the exclusion list, I can still track users who land on the website from Facebook (posts, groups, etc).

Comment: It seems like it works that way. I can't tell for sure since we have some recurring users still coming to the website (and attributed to Facebook CDN). However, the traffic attributed to the referral decreased a lot during the last few days. The traffic is now attributed to the right source, not on Facebook CDN.